# Obtaining something like NDVI value from Sentinel-1 product

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-1

Is there a way to get the some data about biomass from sentinel-1 product? Then try to convert it to NDVI value.
Maybe have some way to get RGB value?

Answer (score 5):

Um, the [Sentinel-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-1) sensor is [C-band SAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_band) (radar) data, not spectral. Given that NDVI is a spectral index of photosynthetically active radiation using the ratio between Red and NIR spectra, what makes you think that you can get NDVI from SAR polarisation? There is absolutely no way to derive NDVI from SAR data!

Please, go research some basics on active and passive remote sensing as well as spectral indices. In your case, even a Google search will provide a starting point.

Comment: Do you mean that no way to get NDVI from sentinel-1 products?

Comment: @Sant No way whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe is there a way to get something like biomass value?

Comment: @Sant, absolutely, biomass estimates are perfectly suited for this type of sensor.

Comment: I have found some research papers about biomass estimation like forests but cant found any anything about fields.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how reliable the study results eventually really are (i.e. how well they generalize to other areas), but at least there is first empirical evidence that an NDVI approximation can be estimated from Sentinel-1 C-band SAR backscatter inputs:

Filgueiras, R., Mantovani, E. C., Althoff, D., Fernandes Filho, E. I., & Cunha, F. F. D. (2019). Crop NDVI Monitoring Based on Sentinel 1. Remote Sensing, 11(12), 1441.